# LEGO Shell Ferrari 2012 Sets

Tags: set-identification

I am looking for information on the 2012 Shell V-Power Ferrari LEGO promotional sets. The sets include a Ferrari truck and a Shell Crew, and some more which I can't remember. Searching in Google brings up very little results. I can't find anything on the LEGO website or the Shell website. The on that I have was bought in Africa, so I don't know if they are avalible in Canada/US too.

What I am looking for is more information on these sets and where I can possibly get them. All I need is website links.

**Picture of Sets:**

[image: LEGO SETS]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brickset is probably the site you need. [Here](http://brickset.com/sets/theme-Racers/subtheme-Ferrari) is a list of the sets you're looking for.

At the moment, it seems the only places you can purchase these are at Chowren Toys or on Bricklink. Brickset has compiled all the available vendors on their "buy tab" when you click on a particular set.

If you haven't ever used Bricklink before, don't fret; it's a pretty straight-forward site. So all you'll need to do is take the link, click on the set you are interested in, click on the buy tab, and that will take you there.

Answer (score 2):

The set numbers are 30190 through 30196, use that to look them up on bricklink/brickset note that 30196 is not shown on your picture, it had some kind of special status in that promotion (I don't remember the details).